# Simple parallel SMD LED circuit(need help)

Tags: voltage, led, surface-mount, parallel

I'm going to make some LED circuits, but I'm not sure if it will work.
The problem is that I want to use Red and Blue leds, but they have different drop voltage. Will this circuit work?
[image]

Comment: Very closely related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't work, or at least not very well.

But not because you have red and blue LEDs.

It won't work because even LEDs with the same color will have slightly different forward voltages, especially if they are at (even slightly) different temperatures.

So your three blue LEDs in parallel won't light up equally, and your three red LEDs in parallel won't light up equally. Possibly the difference in characteristics will even be enough to damage the LEDs.

The better solution is just to use a separate resistor for each LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frnHb0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or, if you have a higher-value voltage source available, place all the LEDs of the same color in series so that they are sure to all get the same current.

Comment: Thanks, so if I use different color leds with resistors for each led(39ohm for blue, 100ohm for red), every led will light equally if I'm correct. What about current, every led needs 20mAh, so will every led get 20mah current? Btw, I'm thinking of soldering 20blue and 20reds all in parallel.

Comment: (4.2-2)/100 = 22 mA, so each of your red LEDs will get about 22 mA. But since the Vf ranges from 1.8 to 2.2 V, there will be some variation (mostly depending on temperature, but also device-to-device). But that's as accurate as you're going to get without using a true constant-current driver. Similar considerations for the blue LEDs, but the variation will actually be higher because the higher Vf forces you to a lower resistor value.

Comment: Also, the human eye doesn't respond equally to different colors so you will need to adjust the current differently between the red and blue LEDs if you want them to appear equally bright.

Comment: If I will use 3528 SMD LED's which needs max 20mAh current, is it safe to use them at 22mAh or I should get 110+ohm resistors?

Comment: It's safer to make sure they are below 20 mA, even when the Vf is at its minimum. Even safer would be to use 4 of each color and run them at 15 mA instead of 20 mA.

Comment: Also, "mAh" is a measurement of battery capacity (how long can the battery supply a given current). For measuring current itself we just use mA.

Comment: Why is it safer to use 4 led's of each color rather than 20? I'm just curious, because I want to solder about 400 different color led's in parallel? Btw, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Because you'd be running them at lower current, so not heating them up as much, they'll last longer. And also in case of any transient, it's less likely they'll be driven above their instantaneous maximum operating point. Of course the drawback is 33% higher cost...which is not a big deal for 3 or 4 LEDs in a hobby project, but if you're talking about 520 vs 400 LEDs, it might be an important consideration.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I understood that it is safer to run them at about ~15mA. But if I solder 120ohm resistors to each of them it doesn't matter if there is 4 or 40led's since all of them have their own resistor and runs at 15mA, or I'm wrong ?

Comment: Yes, each one gets its current set by its own Vf and series resistor.

Comment: I do not want to bother you with my stupid questions, but I got last question(I hope that this is last one :D). Is it big difference in brightness if I run at 15mA or 18mA?
EDIT: I'm confused ltl bit about your formula -->(4.2-2)/100 = 22 mA<-- So if I need 3.4V and use 47ohm resistor--> (4.2-0.8)/47=72mA? (I think something is wrong with my calculation)

Comment: The voltage across the resistor is Vs - Vf (supply voltage minus diode forward voltage). So the current is (Vs - Vf) / R. (4.2-3.4)/47 = 17 mA.

Comment: Thanks. So I think will light up them with ~17mA current to prolong their life :)